# How do you map a field as a generic object in elasticsearch? (doesn't need to be indexed)

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have this this data:

```
{
  "field1": {
    "foo":"bar"
  }
}
```

I would like to map "field1" as an Any object, if possible. I don't need to index it, if that makes it easier. I don't know what the structure of field1 is and can change. So I should be able to update my type to something like:

```
{
    "field1": {
        "foo": 123
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Right now it seems I have to know the mappings of the fields in the "field1" object and cannot deviate from it (except add new fields inside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** tell ES what your field mappings are but you are **not required** to.  Telling ES what your fields are is helpful for ensuring consistency.

That being said, if you just start sending ES a new field it will accept it and create a mapping for it automatically.

In your example when ES sees the new field "foo" with a value of "bar" it's going to automatically create a mapping of "foo" to type "string".

The next time you send in "foo" with a value of 123 ES will still accept that field, but it will be stored as a string.

Good news: ES automatically allows you to do this
Bad news: you can't run "Range" queries on that field (the SQL Equivilent would be: `WHERE FOO > 200`)