# elasticsearch mixed mapping dynamic object

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to do a mapping in elasticsearch for the attached example Json without luck so far, need your help.
the most problematic attribute is the `"info"` and the `"info.value"`.
some time it is empty some time null , int, string ....
an example:

```
 {
    "canArchive": true, 
    "canDelete": true, 
    "canUpdate": true, 
    "hasChildren": false, 
    "id": "777", 
    "info": [
        {
            "defaultValue": null, 
            "editable": true,            
            "value": "", 
            "valueCaption": "", 
            "valueClass": ""
        }, 
        {
            "defaultValue": null, 
            "editable": true,             
            "value": 0, 
            "valueCaption": "", 
            "valueClass": ""
        },
        {
            "defaultValue": null, 
            "editable": true,             
            "value": {
                "12": "Salesforce", 
                "13": "Valooto", 
                "14": "Commissions", 
                "9": "NetSuite"
            }, 
            "valueCaption": null, 
            "valueClass": ""
        }, 
        {
            "defaultValue": null, 
            "editable": true,             
            "value": null, 
            "valueCaption": "", 
            "valueClass": ""
        },
        {
            "defaultValue": null, 
            "editable": false,             
            "value": [
                {
                    "description": "Incident #777 has been changed to Closed", 
                    "extReference": 6, 
                    "id": 3363, 
                    "logTime": "2016-06-14", 
                    "type": "Incident changed", 
                    "userName": "CELLEBRITE\jhamell.hamilton"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": "Incident #777 has been modified", 
                    "extReference": 5, 
                    "id": 1764, 
                    "logTime": "2016-06-08", 
                    "type": "Incident changed", 
                    "userName": "Due Date Rules"
                }, 
                {
                    "description": "Incident #777 priority has been changed to Low", 
                    "extReference": 4, 
                    "id": 1761, 
                    "logTime": "2016-06-08", 
                    "type": "Incident changed", 
                    "userName": "Priority Rules"
                }
            ], 
            "valueCaption": null, 
            "valueClass": ""
        }, 
        {
            "defaultValue": null, 
            "editable": true,             
            "value": "
[http://www.example.com
  Director Customer Support
  T: +99999999999
  M: +99999999999
  E: aaak@bbb.com


text text text text text text text text text text text texttext texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
]
", 
            "valueCaption": "



[http://www.example.com
  Director Customer Support
  T: +99999999999
  M: +99999999999
  E: aaak@bbb.com


text text text text text text text text text text text texttext texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
]
", 
            "valueClass": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please see the following reference :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189906/how-do-you-map-a-field-as-a-generic-object-in-elasticsearch-doesnt-need-to-be